How to combine 2 strings together into one new text string with a new name?
I was trying to add FirstName and LastName together from the Employee table.
CONCAT("FirstName", "LastName")

and I want the result to look the following examples.
I'm expecting to have both FirstName and LastName like this: John Kamara.

OK, so you need a space in there.  CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) AS name.  Right?

Dont' use "" it's generally not needed for column names

Three things:

You need a space between the column values.
CONCAT("FirstName", ' ', "LastName")


While it works, you don't need " quote characters around these column names, and if you did in SQL Server it's idiomatic to use square brackets ([]).
CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName)


While CONCAT() works and is ansi-compliant, in SQL Server it's idiomatic to use the + operator.
FirstName + ' ' + LastName




... new text string with a new name

To give it a name, just put in the name after the expression in the SELECT list:
FirstName + ' ' + LastName FullName

You can also include the As keyword if you really want, but SQL Server doesn't require this.
